# Blazor Hybrid Maui App local Deployment crashes on iPad Air 15.7.3

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, maui, maui-blazor, blazor-hybrid

I am trying to learn and get experience with the new Blazor Hybrid platform. I created a new project and have not modified any code, but cannot get the application deployed to a local iPad. I have an Apple Developer account linked already and have connected it to VS 2022. The application loads to the iPad but crashes on the splash screen after 20 seconds.

I have included the log from the iPad for further details.

```
{"app_name":"Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS","timestamp":"2023-03-27 12:57:08.00-0400","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"7da51ec5-0308-379f-9b12-0c709553dfc2","build_version":"1.0","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.companyname.mauiapptest","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 15.7.3 (19H307)","incident_id":"CAAE2F76-B9E9-45B3-96AA-545B028A68BF","name":"Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS"}
{
  "uptime" : 5800,
  "procLaunch" : "2023-03-27 12:56:46.2966 -0400",
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad5,3",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 139625161304,
  "coalitionID" : 642,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 15.7.3",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "19H307"
  },
"captureTime" : "2023-03-27 12:57:07.1686 -0400",
  "incident" : "CAAE2F76-B9E9-45B3-96AA-545B028A68BF",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 646,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 140126079180,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/BA53F31E-9102-43EB-B98F-B553CA47DE27\/MauiAppTest.app\/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0","CFBundleVersion":"1.0","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.companyname.mauiapptest"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"CFBE26B7-626B-4D09-BB55-A0A1AE122B3B","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
"coalitionName" : "com.companyname.mauiapptest",
  "crashReporterKey" : "044584856d4570d7590ac518853fe87b4bd483f0",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGKILL"},
  "termination" : {"code":2343432205,"flags":6,"namespace":"FRONTBOARD","reasons":["<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:process-launch watchdog transgression: application<com.companyname.mauiapptest>:646 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds","ProcessVisibility: Foreground","ProcessState: Running","WatchdogEvent: process-launch","WatchdogVisibility: Foreground","WatchdogCPUStatistics: (","\"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 22.250 (user 22.250, system 0.000), 36% CPU\",","\"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 18.657, 30% CPU\"",") reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>"]},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":37349,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":4465594624},{"value":0},
{"value":40},{"value":4465594624},{"value":4313249940},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":464},{"value":48},{"value":4465599488},{"value":4465594672},{"value":37349},{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":8000764944,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"__bzero"},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":4465594624},{"value":48},{"value":6},{"value":4392508160},{"value":4371449192},{"value":552},{"value":4413017862},{"value":10777315352},{"value":10777315296},{"value":4395692064}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4313420972},"cpsr":{"value":536870912},"fp":{"value":6155774320},"sp":{"value":6155774304},"esr":{"value":0,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8000765276,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":0}},"name":"tid_103","queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":7516,"symbol":"_platform_memset","symbolLocation":220,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":2315436,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2597828,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2081376,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2049976,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2144548,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":3362916,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":3359312,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":3318660,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":3309788,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":87016,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":270768,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":281476,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":335536,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":284244,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":354236,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":3563364,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":99536,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":444,"imageIndex":2}]},{"id":37365,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6452,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":3}]},{"id":37376,"name":"SGen worker","frames":
 [{"imageOffset":5252,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":39892,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1240,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3063644,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":13128,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":6472,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8000757760,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "ee143597-38ed-3bb7-a5e4-2d7b4243c068",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_platform.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_platform.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4311105536,
    "size" : 4685824,
    "uuid" : "7da51ec5-0308-379f-9b12-0c709553dfc2",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/BA53F31E-9102-43EB-B98F-B553CA47DE27\/MauiAppTest.app\/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS",
    "name" : "Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS"
  },
{
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4318314496,
    "size" : 344064,
    "uuid" : "58ab16ce-d7e0-32d3-946d-4f68fb1a4a17",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8000811008,
    "size" : 69632,
    "uuid" : "ad10e933-2904-3dbc-9575-707033bf6949",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 7457263616,
    "size" : 212992,
    "uuid" : "af565ccf-2e9d-37b0-ae60-c41279a0025a",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  }
],
 
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 6484705280,
  "size" : 2280062976,
  "uuid" : "cb82b2db-fc15-3081-978a-835b03d80016"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=949.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=949.2M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=637.2M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=637.2M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           567.4M       40 \nMALLOC guard page                   64K        4 \nMALLOC_LARGE                        16K        1 \nSTACK GUARD                         48K        3 \nStack                             2096K        3 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       67.7M      151 \n__CTF                               756        1 \n__DATA                            27.6M      856 \n__DATA_CONST                      74.5M      862 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      3206K      701 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       183.7M        3 \n__OBJC_RO                         91.1M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3472K        2 \n__TEXT                           765.5M      868 \n__UNICODE                          592K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nmapped file                       58.3M       19 \nshared memory                       48K        3 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.8G     3523 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "name" : "tid_103",
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
"trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [

  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}
```

Thanks ahead of time.

I have tried adding the below to my csproj file and have verified that my linker is off.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
    <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I have now tried a standard Maui Xaml application versus the Blazor Hybrid and I receive the same outcome. I am thinking it could be a iPad Air issue..

Comment: 1. Is there anything printed in the Application Output in VS when the app is launching? 2. Are you running an empty `.NET 7 MAUI` app on iOS devices?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT
This is what is printed to my console when i run the app

Comment: Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Threading.Thread.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Threading.dll [Exte

Comment: rnal]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Net.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Net.Sockets.dll [Externa

Comment: l]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD847A2B-C357-4A65-B27F-0F4405B60745/MauiAppTest.app/System.Private.Uri.dll [External]
The app has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, this could be a potential issue tracking in [Debugging/Deployment in iOS with net7.0 is broken #13340](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13340).You can follow up on that thread.

Assume that your new Maui project targeting `net7.0` using `Visual Studio 2022` starts to crash on the splash screen after 20 seconds. If that's the case, it can be resolved by changing Target `.NET Runtime` to `net6.0`.

Comment: This project is a .Net 6.0 application 

    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>

Comment: What if you deploy the blank app to another physical iOS device, would that fail?

Comment: I am actually working on getting a new iPad now to see if i get the same outcome. I read in the MS Docs that it could be that the device is too old and the debugger cant launch within the watchdog requirements

Comment: Thanks for the update, let's see if it can work on a new iPad.